# After rotating SKLabelNode it becomes difficult to get location in touchesBegan:

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an SKLabel Node setup as a button in my app and it works fine. However, when I rotate the SKLabelNode with this code my touchesBegan method no longer executes correctly and it becomes very difficult to have the SKLabelNode touches register correctly:

```
[_menuButton runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI  duration:.2],
                                                [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-15 duration:.2]]]];
```

Here is my touches began method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
[self selectNodeForTouch:positionInScene];

if ([node.name isEqualToString:menuButtonName]) {
    //Touched Menu Button
        [self animateMenuAndShow:YES];

}
}
```

EDIT: One additional piece of information is that I'm using SKTEffects which requires that instead of using self.scene as my base I'm using _worldLayer to add all elements in the scene to. Is it possible that this is throwing off my touch calculations? And if so how can I correct this?

```
self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;    
self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

// The origin of the pivot node must be the center of the screen.
_worldPivot = [SKNode node];
[self addChild:_worldPivot];

// Create the world layer. This is the only node that is added directly
// to the pivot node. If you have a HUD layer you would add that directly
// to the scene and make it sit above the world layer.
_worldLayer = [SKNode node];
_worldLayer.position = self.frame.origin;
[_worldPivot addChild:_worldLayer];
```

Also after following sangony's advice here is my updated touchesBegan: method which works well at first, but runs into the same problem after rotating the label by M_PI

```
  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:_worldLayer];
    CGPoint locationInMenu = [touch locationInNode:_menuBackground];

     if (CGRectContainsPoint(_menuButton.frame, location)) {
     //Touched Menu Button

        if (!self.menuVisible) {
           [self animateMenuAndShow:YES];
       }
       else
       {
         [self animateMenuAndShow:NO];
       }
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

Here is my animateMenuAndShow: method

```
-(void)animateMenuAndShow:(BOOL)show
{
    if (show == YES) {
       // self.paused = YES;
       self.menuVisible = !self.menuVisible;

        [self createMenu];


        SKAction *showMenuAction = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                                    [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height/2) duration:0.3],
                                                    [SKAction runBlock:^{
                                                    [self jelly:self.menuBackground];
                                                        }],
                                                    [SKAction waitForDuration:1.5]
                                                    ]];
        [self.menuBackground runAction: showMenuAction completion:^{
            self.paused = YES;
        }];


        if (_flipped == YES) {
            [self.menuBackground runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                                            [SKAction moveByX:0 y:0 duration:.2],[SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI  duration:.2]]]];//   [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI  duration:.2]
        }

    }
    else
    {
       self.paused = NO;

        SKAction *removeMenuAction = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                                      [SKAction         moveTo:CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, -self.size.height + 300) duration:0.3],
                                                      ]];
        [self.menuBackground runAction:removeMenuAction completion:^{
            [self.menuBackground removeFromParent];
        }];

        self.menuVisible = !self.menuVisible;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `touchesBegan` instead:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(myLabel.frame, touchLocation))
        {
            [self animateMenuAndShow:YES];
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my touchesBegan: method with your suggestion and it works fine still, but it takes many touches to get the menu to actually disappear or show after the menu SKLabel has rotated. See my above edit for more info.

Comment: Where and under what circumstances is the rotation action called? Please show the code that checks for animateMenuAndShow and the attached method.

Comment: Ok updated my answer with the animateMenuAndShow method

Comment: I don't think adding to _worldLayer instead of self is any issue. If you can see it, you can touch it. The only issue would be zPosition but you said that it works sometimes so that can also be ruled out. I suggest you do some visual troubleshooting. Add a SKSpriteNode instead of the Label. Make the size the same as the label and color it red so you can see the whole node. Then do your rotation and see how it displays. This might give you some additional clues.